# Can not install app because Websphere SRVE0303 error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I tried to install my app to websphere but it returns to me SRVE0303 error which mean `servlet name for servlet mapping /blahblah not found`.
Here is my `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JmsMessageSenderServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.oep.mq.servlet.JmsMessageSenderServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JmsMessageSenderServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sendMessage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know about servlet 3.0(we use 2.5 servlet-api) that allow to use annotations for mapping servlets, but  i can not change servlet api version.

Comment: Is it just the typo where the second `</servlet-class>` should instead be `</url-pattern>`?

Comment: yes, it was just typo. This is not a reason why i has the error

Comment: And the error is when you install, correct? Not when you try to access the servlet after install? And the error is actually, "servlet name for servlet mapping /sendMessage not found"?

Comment: i install app, but when i try to start it, it would not start. At server logs i found SRVE0303E.

Comment: You should probably edit the question to add those details. You should probably also paste the full WebSphere error message from the log. Next question, just to be sure... the class `ru.oep.mq.servlet.JmsMessageSenderServlet` is definitely in your deployed application? In WEB-INF/classes or in a jar file?

Comment: @dbreaux `ru.oep.mq.servlet.JmsMessageSenderServlet` in my deployed application. error from log `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.webapp.webappconfugurationhelper constructServletMappings SRVE0303: servlet name for servlet mapping /sendMessage not found`

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was in `<web-app>` tag in `web.xml`. i was should need to add `metadata-complete="true"`.